# Upgrade the package php5 (PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.26) to php 5.6+

Tags: 12.04, apt, upgrade, php

We have a mission critical server that cannot be rebooted and need to upgrade to php 5.6 for some scripts we are running.

The OS is quite old (Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS). I have run through some tutorials and installed php5.6 (separate package) however that left me with 2 versions of php, apache would use one and CLI would use another. As i said this server cannot go down.

Is there any way to upgrade the package php5 to a newer version? Or is there a way to migrate gracefully to php5.6, modules, ini files etc ?

I have tried upgrade, however apparently we have the latest version.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: 12.04 will reach its end of life tomorrow, 28 April. You should upgrade to 14.04.

Comment: Pushing unsupported upgrades to a mission-critical server that is EOL? That seems like the three legs of the guaranteed-to-fail tripod. If the organization is unwilling to mitigate nor consider a smarter course, then run away. You don't want your fingerprints anywhere near this looming disaster.